# Windows could not start the Apache CouchDB service on Local Computer

Tags: apache, service, couchdb

I have installed CouchDB on my Windows machine but while starting the CouchDB service, I am getting a message like:

> Windows could not start the Apache CouchDB service on Local Computer. The service did not return an error. This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.

As the service is not running, I am unable to access Fauxton too.

I am using Windows 7. CouchDB is 2.0.0. Port 5984 is not in use.

Comment: Do you have a previous version of CouchDB installed? Do you have any other logs in your Windows Events? Do you have any logs into the CouchDB/var/log/couchdb/couch.log file?

Comment: nope. Its a fresh installation. No logs even.

Comment: Which version of CouchDB? What OS version do you have? Is the port 5984 already used?

Comment: I am using windows 7. CouchDB is 2.0.0. Obviously 5984 is not in use, initial checks are already done from my end.

Comment: I guess you already tried to reinstall it?

Comment: yes tried everything, still not working and unable to find the solution. For the time being, i have installed that on a linux based remote machine and accessing it from there, but still looking for a solution.

Comment: Do you have any spaces in the installation path?

Comment: obviously NO - i have tried everything/all solutions provided on stackoverflow and other similar websites. And this check was advised in most of the websites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44107335/219187 because you are on Windows 7, and the **problem described there is for Windows 10 with the creators update**.

But maybe the solution fixes your problem as well? Here is the procedure:

1. Download the prelease build 2.2.4-101 from https://nssm.cc/download
2. Stop the CouchDB service through the Windows Services dialog (paused is not enough)
3. Overwrite `nssm.exe` in `<CouchDbInstallDir>\bin` with the one from the downloaded ZIP file (make sure you pick the right version 32 bit / 64 bit)
4. Start the CouchDB service

Answer (score 0):

Issue it's happening since the last updates released by Microsoft. I'm not completely aware of what's causing it, but I think it's something related to CouchDB service not been able to start using Local Administrator rights.
However I've managed to start the service manually, by doing so:

1. Open Command Prompt - in the Search from the Start Menu or Task Bar type "**cmd**"
2. Run it as an Administrator - right click on the Command Prompt application and choose "**Run as administrator**" option /this is really **IMPORTANT** as it will allow the service to have administrator access/
3. Navigate to the folder where CouchDB is install - default path is "**D:/CouchDB**", but could be anywhere else; you have to find it
4. Go to the "**bin**" folder in there
5. Type "**couchdb**" as a command to start the service
6. You will see a message showing after this - "**kernel-poll not supported; "K" parameter ignored**"
7. If it adds some error messages after it or closes the whole terminal, you're making some things bad from this guide, so follow it strictly.
8. You can now open up the *Fauxton* application in the browser like normal from here - http://localhost:5984/_utils/

Keep in mind that you have to leave the cmd opened in order the service to be working as expected. As far as I saw no information was lost, so it's all good.
This is a temporary solution though, as we are waiting a relase from either Microsoft or Apache to solve the issue, or at least give us more explanation about it.

Comment: I am not getting any other error message, even the terminal is not closing off for a moment, I am getting a window-popup of erl.exe has stopped working, which i guess somehow erlang is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

i just met the same problem.
the cause is space, you have to install CouchDB in a path without any space, even Program Files folder, because there is a space between Program and Files...