# CouchDB fails to start after applying Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: windows, service, windows-10, couchdb

I'm running CouchDB 2.0 on Windows for development purposes. After applying the Windows 10 Creators Update, the CouchDB service doesn't start anymore. When I try to start it manually, I get a generic "unable to start service" error message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CouchDB 2.0 on Windows uses the [Non-Sucking Service Manager (NSSM)](https://nssm.cc/) to run itself as service. Apparently, NSSM has problems after the creators update has been applied:

> 2017-04-26: Users of Windows 10 Creators Update should use prelease build 2.2.4-101 to avoid an issue with services failing to start.

Thus, the problem can be fixed by using the mentioned build of NSSM:

1. Download the pre-release build 2.2.4-101 from https://nssm.cc/download
2. Stop the CouchDB service through the Windows Services dialog (paused is not enough)
3. Overwrite `nssm.exe` in `<CouchDbInstallDir>\bin` with the one from the downloaded ZIP file (make sure you pick the right version 32 bit / 64 bit)
4. Start the CouchDB service