# CouchDb service not starting on localhost Windows 10

Tags: service, erlang, windows-10, couchdb

When I check the services running it shows the Apache CouchDb service running, but on hitting localhost:5984/_utils it's showing Site can't be reached.

I tried replacing the nssm.exe in bin folder of couchdb installation directory as specified in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44107335/219187, but with no sucesss.
Iam getting the following error

```
[error] 2017-11-09T15:52:03.730000Z couchdb@localhost <0.201.0> -------- 
Supervisor couch_primary_services had child collation_driver started with 
couch_drv:start_link() at undefined exit with reason "The specified module 
could not be found." in context start_error
[error] 2017-11-09T15:52:03.730000Z couchdb@localhost <0.199.0> -------- 
Supervisor couch_sup had child couch_primary_services started with 
couch_primary_sup:start_link() at undefined exit with reason {shutdown,
{failed_to_start_child,collation_driver,"The specified module could not be 
found."}} in context start_error
[error] 2017-11-09T15:52:03.731000Z couchdb@localhost <0.197.0> -------- 
CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.197.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: 
{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_primary_services,{shutdown,
{failed_to_start_child,collation_driver,"The specified module could not be 
found."}}}},{couch_app,start,[normal,[]]}} at 
application_master:init/4(line:134) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); 
initial_call: {application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2',...]}, 
ancestors: [<0.196.0>], messages: [{'EXIT',<0.198.0>,normal}], links: 
[<0.196.0>,<0.7.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, 
heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 139
[info] 2017-11-09T15:52:03.731000Z couchdb@localhost <0.7.0> -------- 
Application couch exited with reason: {{shutdown,
{failed_to_start_child,couch_primary_services,{shutdown,
{failed_to_start_child,collation_driver,"The specified module could not be 
found."}}}},{couch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}

[error] 2017-11-09T15:52:07.921000Z couchdb@localhost <0.202.0> -------- 
CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.202.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: "The 
specified module could not be found." at gen_server:init_it/6(line:344) <= 
proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_drv,init,
['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_primary_services,couch_sup,<0.198.0>], 
messages: [], links: [<0.201.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: 
running, heap_size: 376, stack_size: 27, reductions: 125
[error] 2017-11-09T15:52:07.922000Z couchdb@localhost <0.198.0> -------- 
Error starting Apache CouchDB:
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version? Have you install CouchDB on a path with spaces?

Comment: latest version 2.1.1

Comment: my installation directory is the default one C:\CouchDB without spaces

Comment: I have the same problem ("...failed_to_start_child...The specified module could not be found..."), except I'm running windows 7. I'm also installing couch db to the default C:\CouchDB. Did you come across a solution?