# CouchDB service does not startup correctly after installation

Tags: couchdb

I have installed CouchDB (v2.2.0) on a Windows 7 Pro laptop. I have installed to the default C:\CouchDB location. Installation does not report any errors.

However when I try navigate to localhost:5984 to verify my installation, I receive a site unreachable error.

I have tried uninstalling, restarting and re-installing to no avail.

I'm hoping someone else has experienced the same and found a solution. I cannot find any guidance on the couchdb site. What follows is an extract of my couch.log file:

> [info] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.315000Z couchdb@localhost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_log started on node couchdb@localhost
>   [info] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.334000Z couchdb@localhost <0.7.0> -------- Application folsom started on node couchdb@localhost
>   [info] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.373000Z couchdb@localhost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_stats started on node couchdb@localhost
>   [info] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.373000Z couchdb@localhost <0.7.0> -------- Application khash started on node couchdb@localhost
>   [info] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.389000Z couchdb@localhost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_event started on node couchdb@localhost
>   [info] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.405000Z couchdb@localhost <0.7.0> -------- Application ibrowse started on node couchdb@localhost
>   [info] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.405000Z couchdb@localhost <0.7.0> -------- Application ioq started on node couchdb@localhost
>   [info] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.405000Z couchdb@localhost <0.7.0> -------- Application mochiweb started on node couchdb@localhost
>   [info] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.420000Z couchdb@localhost <0.198.0> -------- Apache CouchDB 2.1.2 is starting.
>
> [info] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.420000Z couchdb@localhost <0.199.0> -------- Starting couch_sup
>   [error] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.420000Z couchdb@localhost <0.202.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.202.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: "The specified module could not be found." at gen_server:init_it/6(line:344) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_drv,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_primary_services,couch_sup,<0.198.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.201.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: running, heap_size: 376, stack_size: 27, reductions: 125
>   [error] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.420000Z couchdb@localhost <0.198.0> -------- Error starting Apache CouchDB:

```
{error,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_primary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,collation_driver,"The specified module could not be found."}}}}}
```

> [error] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.436000Z couchdb@localhost <0.201.0> -------- Supervisor couch_primary_services had child collation_driver started with couch_drv:start_link() at undefined exit with reason "The specified module could not be found." in context start_error
>   [error] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.436000Z couchdb@localhost <0.199.0> -------- Supervisor couch_sup had child couch_primary_services started with couch_primary_sup:start_link() at undefined exit with reason {shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,collation_driver,"The specified module could not be found."}} in context start_error
>   [error] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.436000Z couchdb@localhost <0.197.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.197.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_primary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,collation_driver,"The specified module could not be found."}}}},{couch_app,start,[normal,[]]}} at application_master:init/4(line:134) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2',...]}, ancestors: [<0.196.0>], messages: [{'EXIT',<0.198.0>,normal}], links: [<0.196.0>,<0.7.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 139
>   [info] 2018-09-25T13:22:21.436000Z couchdb@localhost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_primary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,collation_driver,"The specified module could not be found."}}}},{couch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}

Comment: Do you have a previous installation of CouchDB?. The trace shows that you are running version 2.1.2: "Apache CouchDB 2.1.2 is starting."

Comment: Hi @JuanjoRodriguez, I uninstalled 2.2.0 and tried 2.1.2 as part of my problem solving effort - no luck as 2.1.2 exhibited the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar error in windows 8.1 for couchdb-2.2.0 , I got mine working after trying few of the steps mentioned in the below answers.

Although It seems like it has something to do with Mysql but I did not uninstall mysql. I think its not able to correctly parse the windows style path variable entries(having spaces).

[Windows could not start the Apache CouchDB service on Local Computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761390/windows-could-not-start-the-apache-couchdb-service-on-local-computer)

[CouchDB fails to start after applying Windows 10 Creators Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107334/couchdb-fails-to-start-after-applying-windows-10-creators-update/44107335)

1. Replace nssm.exe
2. Start couchdb from cmd (Administrator)
3. It failed first time, erl.exe crashed,it will prompt for adding to firewall exception , allow.
4. running couchdb.cmd again got it working.

[Starting CouchDB from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpT9d.png)

Comment: I no longer have access to the machine in question to confirm your solution, but hopefully your comment will help some other traveller ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove MySQL entries from your PATH variable. Uninstalling MSQL is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Herewith an answer to my own question:

The problem seems to be related to a MySQL 5.6 installation.

I suspected that there was a clash with the 2 apps because as soon as I installed couchDB, I'd get occassional errors reported in the MySQL service.

I uninstalled MySQL and reinstalled couch db and it runs with no issues now. I'll try install MySQL again and see if this happens again.

For now, this issue is resolved.